# AJAX: stops running at readyState = 1

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here's my script:

```
var Ajax = {

    init: function(){
        try{            
            this.xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();            
        }        
        catch( e ){            
            try{                
                this.xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHttp" );                
            }            
            catch( e ){                
            }            
        }        
        return this;
    },

    get: function( url , async , fn ){
        this.xmlHttp.open( "GET" , url , async );
        console.log( "1" );
        this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type' , 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
        console.log( this.xmlHttp.readyState );
        this.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            console.log( "3" );
            if( this.xmlHttp.readyState == 4 ){
                if( this.xmlHttp.status == 200 ){
                    try{
                        if( fn ) return fn( this.xmlHttp.responseText );
                    }
                    catch( e ){
                        alert( e );
                    }
                }
                else alert( "bad status" );
            }
            else alert( "bad state" );
        }
    }

}
```

And the line to call it:

```
Ajax.init().get( "localhost/engine.php" , true , function( txt ){alert(txt)});
```

Now, at the console I get this:

```
1
1
```

Hence, I understand the running stucks at `this.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){` while the readyState is 1. Could you, please, tell me, what's wrong here? Am I missing some bigger error here?

**After researching a bit, it seems like the xmlHttp does not really open the url (no request is seen in Chrome's console and Firebug)...**

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751269/ajax-wont-get-past-readystate-1-why

Comment: @Sudhir not really. I need it crossbrowsed, can't depend on `.onload`

Comment: Try to understand [this example,](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) it might give you clear idea that whats wrong in your code. Also you can try with debugging your javascript using firebug in mozilla.

Comment: I've been using AJAX for a long time, but not the way I wrote above. I know how it works (or, I guess, I thought I know). The problem is in this script and I just miss it...

Comment: You need to output the value of `readyState` inside the callback for it changing, not directly after you made the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never actually starting the request! Add this at the end of your get() function:

```
this.xmlHttp.send();
```

Hope this helps