# jQuery ajax success callback function - how to make it anonymous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am unable to get the success callback to work in a jQuery ajax call.  The following code calls `interpretResponse()` just fine, but of course `resultJSON` is `undefined`:

```
        var that = this;
        jQuery('#fsForm1492441').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "format_result.php",
                data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
                success: that.interpretResponse(),
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });

        function interpretResponse(resultJSON) {
        // code here to handle resultJSON
        }
```

I want something like:

```
                success: function(resultJSON) { 
                         that.interpretResponse(resultJSON); 
                         },
```

How should the `success` callback be written?

Comment: rather than setting `dataType:'json'`, you should set the header on the file you're calling to be `'Content-type:application/json'`. FAR more reliable, and less JS to parse.

Answer (score 1):

just do this :

```
success: interpretResponse,
```

your code will look like this -

```
var that = this;
jQuery('#fsForm1492441').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "format_result.php",
        data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
        success: interpretResponse,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});

function interpretResponse(resultJSON) {
    // code here to handle resultJSON
}
```

Comment: `interpretResponse` is not an object property. It should probably just be `success: interpretResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above was correct, but it turned out that I was dealing with a different problem.  The weird bug in FireFox that keeps ajax calls from getting past readyState 1 was causing the callback function to not load.  I ended up using the workaround described here:
[Ajax won't get past readyState 1, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751269/ajax-wont-get-past-readystate-1-why)
Basically getting Firefox to set the callback `onload` rather than `onreadystatechange`.

Thanks to pXL for the answer to the question the way I asked it.